# Ansible attach multiple files in single mail

Tags: ansible, email-attachments

I am trying to attach multiple files in single mail. I have to attach my host logs within this mail, which gets generated dynamically. As off now I have 2 hosts. Dynamic files are generated in /ansible_log/10.0.0.1_log.txt & /ansible_log/10.0.0.2_log.txt (and so on). Here I can send mail, below is the script:

```
Inventory File:
[logs]
x.x.x.1
x.x.x.2

- name: Send e-mail to users, attaching report
  mail:
    host: x.x.x.x
    port: xx
    to: "{{ mailid }}"
    subject: Server Logs
    body: Please find attached logs.
    attach:
      - /ansible_log/{{ item }}_log.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  run_once: True
  tags: send_mail
```

Here I want to send a mail which attaches both log files in a single mail. If I remove `run_once: True` then it sends two seperate mails with 2 host log files. If the inventory list grows, then these log files mails will bombard user mail box. To avoid this I want to consolidate all the log files in a single mail and to the recipient as a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a loop there. You must give it a prebuild list of files.

You can use a setfact task to build a list of files before running this task.

Comment: Hi Sorin, I tried that as well. 
- name: add hostname into variable
  set_fact:
     hostList: "/ansible_log/{{ inventory_hostname }}_log.txt"
  tags: send_mail
Still it sent only one file.